# Forms w/document folder -> SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, remote-blob-storage

I am trying to find what is the better way to implement multiple input forms using SharePoint 2007 (v3). The forms will have several fields and one of them is document folder to hold documents and subfolders. How would I start with that? Can I use some existing templates and develop in top of them. will use c# to develop or vb.

should I use sharepoint or start own application.
Concern are: 
- I have large data size over 300gb of documents and since sharepoint use DB to store them I am not sure about perfomance (SP vs local share). Also is there a way to have sharepoint store docs in Lan share with ability to still have checkin/out.

- Searching form contents and documents in the folders and tags
- Migrating to SharePoint 2010
- querying and updating db and adding own tables
- limitation on sharepoint development
  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have InfoPath licensed, that is certainly a decent way to go for building input forms, but building them with Visual Studio in VB or C# is not a monumental task either:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732(v=office.12).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2006/09/05/application-development-on-moss-2007-amp-wss-v3.aspx

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingCodeBehindFilesInSharePointSites.aspx

As far as storage goes, your options are somewhat limited with 2007 because there is no OOB capability to remote the BLOBs like there is in SharePoint 2010 (i.e. RBS FILESTREAM). You do have EBS at your disposal and there are multiple ISVs out there that provide mature EBS providers. If you look at this make sure whatever option you choose provides an upgrade path to SharePoint 2010 and SQL RBS.

I used to be the CTO for the StoragePoint product, so I'll give that one a nod because I know it works...and works well.  http://www.storagepoint.com

Seriously think about upgrading to 2010 because you have more storage options.

Comment: Rob, other than markting for that system I did not seem to learn anything in regard to my question. I am looking to develop in c#. What is the storage problem? Search options? adding own tables. and develop own procedures (functions) to handle relational database? would I loose the check in/ check out functionality in SP if I develop my own connected forms that needs to link to files/folders. thanks

Comment: You asked a 2 part question...I provided references that demonstrate how easily you can build forms and a recommendation on StoragePoint only because I know te product...remote BLOB storage has zero impact on development, search, or OOB docman features (i.e. Check in/ check out).